# PHP - регулярный выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Сейчас пишу парсер html страниц. Для этого получаю dom страницы и считываю все ссылки. Для того, чтобы узнать является ли ссылка, ссылкой на статью, мне нужно сначала удалить все теги в теге a, вместе с содержимым, и после получить текст.
Для этого я использую регулярные выражения, чаще всего попадаются такие теги, как div, span, b, i, p, strong. Чтобы их очистить, я использую 6 регулярных выражений.

```
$clean_title = preg_replace("'<span[^>]*?>.*?</span>'si","", $title);
$clean_title = preg_replace("'<p[^>]*?>.*?</p>'si","", $clean_title);
$clean_title = preg_replace("'<div[^>]*?>.*?</div>'si","", $clean_title);
$clean_title = preg_replace("'<strong[^>]*?>.*?</strong>'si","", $clean_title);
$clean_title = preg_replace("'<i[^>]*?>.*?</i>'si","", $clean_title);
$clean_title = preg_replace("'<b[^>]*?>.*?</b>'si","", $clean_title);
```

Как можно соединить их в одно регулярное выражение, вместо 6?

Comment: зачем вы мучаете дом и себя :) загрузите в DOMDocument и найдите все элементы a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разбираться с HTML при помощи регулярных выражений дело совсем неблагодарное. Давайте это сделаем более-менее правильно. Вот так вы получите список всех ссылок     в документе, а дальше отбирайте нужные...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($pageHtml);
$a = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach($a as $item) {
      $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");
      $text = $item->nodeValue;
    }
```

Comment: Все верно, но мне нужно получить именно текст, который находится внутри ссылок и узнать его длину, чтобы узнать заголовок это или нет. Для этого, после получения ссылок тем способом, что вы описали выше, мне нужно удалить из них все лишние теги, вместе с лишним текстом.

Comment: вы хотите сказать, что nodeValue дает innerhtml ?